# How can I reattach to tmux process

Tags: tmux

I had to reboot my box today. I had several program running in tmux sessions. They seem to be still alive, how can I reattach to them?
I tried `tmux a processID` but it didn't work.

```
/home/me 21$ ps aux | grep tmux
me    1299  0.0  0.0  22244  1920 ?        Ss   Apr28   0:40 tmux -2 -f /tmp/r-plugin-me/tmux.conf new-session -s vimrpluginme1398670569alnn51oynp1vollnn51f2v4r_ied_delta1meRalphaCalibr VIMINSTANCEID=alnn51oynp1vollnn51f2v4r_ied_delta1meRal
me    2575  0.0  0.0  54164  3500 ?        S    07:35   0:00 xterm -e tmux -2 -f /home/me/.tmux.conf -S /tmp/vX0qRrR/78
me    2577  0.0  0.0  19892  1400 pts/2    Ss+  07:35   0:00 tmux -2 -f /home/me/.tmux.conf -S /tmp/vX0qRrR/78
me    2579  0.0  0.0  22128  1832 ?        Ss   07:35   0:00 tmux -2 -f /home/me/.tmux.conf -S /tmp/vX0qRrR/78
me    5155  0.0  0.0   6380   756 pts/4    S+   07:46   0:00 grep tmux
me   31340  0.0  0.0  23348  3000 ?        Ss   Apr28   0:17 tmux -2 -f /home/me/.tmux.conf -S /tmp/vIqEM06/78
```

Comment: I assume you mean the `tmux` sessions are running on another machine, because I don't see how they would survive a reboot by the machine they are running on.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can not re-attach a process id. You need to reattach the corresponding `tmux` session.

So do `tmux ls`. Pick whatever session you want to re-attach. Then do `tmux attach -d -t <session id>` to re-attach it to a new tmux instance and release it from the old one.

Comment: it's also hand to just use `tmux attach` if you only have one session you've detached from.

Comment: `tmux a -t <session id>` also seemed to work for me.

Comment: `tmux attach -d -t` also worked for me when I detached from a session using `Ctrl + b +d` but `tmux ls` was still showing that session as attached.

Comment: `-d` means "Detach others on the session (Maximize window by detach other clients)"  [reference](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com). If there is only one session, `tmux attach -d -t session_name` is [fine](https://superuser.com/questions/610608/detach-the-other-tmux-clients).

Comment: `tmux -d` is used to Detach others who are in the session - [details](https://www.debugpointer.com/linux/how-to-disconnect-all-other-tmux-users).

Answer (score 41):

If you only have one session detached you can just do

```
tmux attach
```

also if you're going to be working in multiple sessions it might be a good idea to name your sessions

```
tmux new -s ssh-to-staging
Ctrl b, d   # Detach from session
tmux new -s ssh-to-s3
Ctrl b, d   Detach from session
```

now when you do `tmux ls` you can reattach more easily without guessing.

```
tmux attach -d -t ssh-to-s3
```

You also might wanna [bookmark this cheat sheet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tmux%20cheat%20sheet&atb=v86-5__&ia=cheatsheet&iax=cheatsheet&iai=r1-9&page=1&sexp=%7B%22cdrexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22artexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22prodexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22prdsdexp%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22msvrtexp%22%3A%22b%22%7D)

Comment: Is it possible to name a session after the fact?

Comment: @JoelMellon yes see cheat sheet linked in the answer